# Cannot output multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, oop, download

I cannot get any output from my multi-dimensional array. I'm trying to get my data using the push_array method.

I would like to get my output as:

- John, 1001
- Tom, 1002
- Jerry, 1003
- Sarah, 1004

However, I'm not getting any output. I know the array is working though as I get the following output when I echo $message and do not use $id and $name in my output foreach array.

Current output: (when echoing $message)

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

But nothing gets shown when I use $id and $name as shown here.

```
<ul class="result"><?php
    foreach ($output as $message) {
        $id = $message[1][0];
        $name = $message[1][1];
    ?><li>
        <a href="handleDownload.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name; ?>      </a>
    </li><php } ?>
</ul>
```

Here is my full code:

```
<?php 
$Download = new Download();
$result = array(); //store results of upload
try {
    $Download->showDBFiles();
    $output = $Download->getMessages();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result[] = $e->getMessage();
}

?>

<h2>Output</h2>
<?php if ($output) { ?>
    <ul class="result">
    <?php  foreach ($output as $message) {
        $id = $message[1][0];
        $name = $message[1][1];
    ?>
        <li><a href="handleDownload.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Function where arrays are defined

```
protected $messages = array();

        public function showDBFiles() {
            global $database;
            $values=array();
            $sql = "SELECT resume_id, resume_title FROM ".self::$table_name;
            $result = $database->query($sql);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
                 $this->messages[] = "Database is empty";
            }else{
                while(list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    array_push($this->messages, array($id, $name));
                }
            }
        }

        public function getMessages()
        {
                return $this->messages;
        }
```

UPDATE: 
After using the suggestion by jedrzej.kurylo I'm able to have the $id and $name values as shown in my var_dump output:

array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "73" [1]=> string(2) "qd" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "72" [1]=> string(3) "jav" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "70" [1]=> string(4) "da12" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "71" [1]=> string(3) "jav" } }

However for some reason that I'm unsure of my output is now this:

- d
- a
- a
- a

Comment: Show us your results for `var_dump($output)`

Comment: "However, I'm not getting any output. I know the array is working though as I get the following output when I echo $message and do not use $id and $name in my output foreach array." - if you are seing integer values when outputting $message it means that $message is not an array, so you won't be able to take id and name out of it

Comment: I get: array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) }

Comment: If in the `foreach` loop you write `print_r($message)`, what do you see?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Oh I see. I'm still quite new to this and did not realise that. How I can correct my codes?

Comment: See the answer I just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you use **array_push** here:

```
$this->messages[] = array_push($values, array($id, $name));
```

**array_push** does not return updated array but the new number of items in the array - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php. That's why you're getting increasing integers in your output.

Do the following instead:

```
while(list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($this->messages, array($id, $name));
}
```

or just

```
while(list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $this->messages[] = array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name);
}
```

Then you can access **$id** and **$name** like this:

```
$id = $message['id'];
$name = $message['name'];
```

Comment: My output still isn't as expected though. (I've updated my answer to reflect this)                                                                                                I'm able to get my id and name from the array now thanks to your suggestion as my vardump output is: array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "73" [1]=> string(2) "qd" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "72" [1]=> string(3) "jav" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "70" [1]=> string(4) "da12" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "71" [1]=> string(3) "jav" } }

Comment: I've updated the answer - changed how array is saved in $this->messages[] so that you can easily access the fields by names + added info on how to display $id and $name