# echo values of 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an 2 dimensional array that is used to display a survey.  The array contains 63 rows (questions).  Each row contains a GpDesc (Grouping ie. Leadership Traits) and a QueDesc (question).  There are 9 different GpDesc.  I would like to echo the GpDesc at the first occurrence and then echo the questions and radio buttons within that group until the next GpDesc.  I know that I need an outer loop for the number of GpDesc and an inner loop for the questions within that group but I don't know how to do this. Here is part of $varArray:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10266 
        [QueDesc] => Is visionary 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10267 
        [QueDesc] => Possesses high degree of integrity 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10268 
        [QueDesc] => Displays an enthusiastic, positive outlook 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10269 
        [QueDesc] => Uses good executive judgment 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10270 
        [QueDesc] => Provides effective leadership 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10271 
        [QueDesc] => Organizes and administers in a confident manner 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10272 
        [QueDesc] => Acts fairly and decisively on important issues 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10273 
        [QueDesc] => Displays effective strategic planning 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10274 
        [QueDesc] => Establishes appropriate goals and objectives 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [9] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10275 
        [QueDesc] => Defines appropriate priorities 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [10] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1168 
        [GpDesc] => LEADERSHIP TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10276 
        [QueDesc] => Entertains new ideas 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [11] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1169 
        [GpDesc] => MANAGEMENT TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10277 
        [QueDesc] => Involves faculty in strategic planning 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [12] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1169 
        [GpDesc] => MANAGEMENT TRAITS 
        [QueID] => 10278 
        [QueDesc] => Utilizes departmental advisory group or other clientele in decision making 
        [GpQue] => 0 
    ) 
    [13] => Array ( 
        [GpID] => 1169 
        [GpDesc] =>
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you replace that dump with the result of a `print_r($array);` or at least a few occurances of it

Comment: Sorry about the mess, but here is part of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot output multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702980/cannot-output-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$survey =
Array(
                Array (
                        'GpID' => 1168,
                        'GpDesc' => 'LEADERSHIP TRAITS',
                        'QueID' => 10266,
                        'QueDesc' => 'Is visionary',
                        'GpQue' => 0
                      ),
                Array (
                        'GpID' => 1168,
                        'GpDesc' => 'LEADERSHIP TRAITS',
                        'QueID' => 10267,
                        'QueDesc' => 'Possesses high degree of integrity',
                        'GpQue' => 0
                      ),
                Array (
                        'GpID' => 1169,
                        'GpDesc' => 'MANAGEMENT TRAITS',
                        'QueID' => 10277,
                        'QueDesc' => 'Involves faculty in strategic planning',
                        'GpQue' => 0
                      ),
                Array (
                        'GpID' => 1169,
                        'GpDesc' => 'MANAGEMENT TRAITS',
                        'QueID' => 10278,
                        'QueDesc' => 'Utilizes departmental advisory group or other clientele in decision making',
                        'GpQue' => 0
                      )
                );

echo $survey[0]['GpDesc'].PHP_EOL;
$prevGpId = $survey[0]['GpID'];

foreach ($survey as $line) {
        if ($line['GpID'] !== $prevGpId) {
                echo $line['GpDesc'].PHP_EOL;
                $prevGpId = $line['GpID'];
        }
        echo "\t".$line['QueDesc'].PHP_EOL;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  That's exactly what I needed.